# Пакетирование аудио данных типа pcm_alaw в mka аудиофайл, используя ffmpeg API

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encoder

**UPD**

Представим, что в моем проекте, я получаю `RTP` пакеты с типом полезной нагрузки-[8](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/rtp.htm), для последующего сохранения данной нагрузки в качестве N-й части аудиодорожки. Я извлекаю эту нагрузку из пакета `RTP` и сохраняю ее во временный буфер:

```cpp
...

while ((rtp = receiveRtpPackets()).withoutErrors()) {
   payloadData.push(rtp.getPayloadData());
}

audioGenerator.setPayloadData(payloadData);
audioGenerator.recordToFile();

...
```

После заполнения временного буфера определенного размера данной полезной нагрузкой, я обрабатываю этот буфер, а именно, извлекаю всю полезную нагрузку и кодирую с использованием [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/developer.html) для дальнейшего сохранения в аудиофайл, формата [Matroska](https://www.matroska.org/index.html). Но у меня есть проблема. Поскольку полезная нагрузка пакета `RTP` имеет тип `8`, я должен сохранить сырые аудиоданные формата [pcm_alaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm) в `mka` формат аудио. Но при сохранение сырых данный `pcm_alaw` в аудиофайл, я получаю такие вот сообщения, со стороны библиотеки:

```bsh
...

[libopus @ 0x18eff60] Queue input is backward in time
[libopus @ 0x18eff60] Queue input is backward in time
[libopus @ 0x18eff60] Queue input is backward in time
[libopus @ 0x18eff60] Queue input is backward in time

...
```

При открытии аудиофайла в [vlc](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/), ничего не воспроизводится (временная метка аудиодорожки отсутствует).

**Задача моего проекта** заключается в том, чтобы просто взять `pcm_alaw` данные и **запаковать их в контейнер**, формата `mka`. Благодаря комментарию пользователя [Fat-Zer](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/277616/fat-zer), было определено, что лучше всего использовать для определения кодека - [av_guess_codec()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavf__encoding.html#gae8a1efab53a348857f209ea51037da4c) функцию, которая в свою очередь, автоматически подбирает нужный идентификатор кодека. Но как мне запаковать сырые данные в контейнер правильно, я не знаю.

**Важно отметить**, что я могу получить в качестве сырых данных любой формат этих данных (только **аудио форматы**), определенный по типу `RTP` пакета ([Все](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_payload_formats) типы полезной нагрузки `RTP` пакета). Известно лишь то, что в любом случае, **я должен упаковать аудиоданные в `mka` контейнер**.

Прилагаю и код (позаимствовал с [этого](https://www.programmersought.com/article/2635152445/) ресурса), который я использую:

**audiogenerater.h**

```cpp
extern "C"
{
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libswresample/swresample.h"
}

class AudioGenerater
{
public:

    AudioGenerater();
   ~AudioGenerater() = default;

    void generateAudioFileWithOptions(
            QString        fileName,
            QByteArray     pcmData,
            int            channel,
            int            bitRate,
            int            sampleRate,
            AVSampleFormat format);
            
private:

    // init Format
    bool initFormat(QString audioFileName);

private:

    AVCodec         *m_AudioCodec        = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext  *m_AudioCodecContext = nullptr;
    AVFormatContext *m_FormatContext     = nullptr;
    AVOutputFormat  *m_OutputFormat      = nullptr;
};
```

**audiogenerater.cpp**

```cpp
AudioGenerater::AudioGenerater()
{
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
}

AudioGenerater::~AudioGenerater()
{
    // ... 
}

bool AudioGenerater::initFormat(QString audioFileName)
{
    // Create an output Format context
    int result = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_FormatContext, nullptr, nullptr, audioFileName.toLocal8Bit().data());
    if (result < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    m_OutputFormat = m_FormatContext->oformat;

    // Create an audio stream
    AVStream* audioStream = avformat_new_stream(m_FormatContext, m_AudioCodec);
    if (audioStream == nullptr) {
        avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return false;
    }

    // Set the parameters in the stream
    audioStream->id = m_FormatContext->nb_streams - 1;
    audioStream->time_base = { 1, 8000 };
    result = avcodec_parameters_from_context(audioStream->codecpar, m_AudioCodecContext);
    if (result < 0) {
        avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return false;
    }

    // Print FormatContext information
    av_dump_format(m_FormatContext, 0, audioFileName.toLocal8Bit().data(), 1);

    // Open file IO
    if (!(m_OutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        result = avio_open(&m_FormatContext->pb, audioFileName.toLocal8Bit().data(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (result < 0) {
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void AudioGenerater::generateAudioFileWithOptions(
    QString _fileName,
    QByteArray _pcmData,
    int _channel,
    int _bitRate,
    int _sampleRate,
    AVSampleFormat _format)
{
    AVFormatContext* oc;
    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(
            &oc, nullptr, nullptr, _fileName.toStdString().c_str())
        < 0) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }
    if (!oc) {
        printf("Could not deduce output format from file extension: using mka.\n");
        avformat_alloc_output_context2(
            &oc, nullptr, "mka", _fileName.toStdString().c_str());
    }
    if (!oc) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }
    AVOutputFormat* fmt = oc->oformat;
    if (fmt->audio_codec == AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }

    AVCodecID codecID = av_guess_codec(
        fmt, nullptr, _fileName.toStdString().c_str(), nullptr, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO);
    // Find Codec
    m_AudioCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecID);
    if (m_AudioCodec == nullptr) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }
    // Create an encoder context
    m_AudioCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_AudioCodec);
    if (m_AudioCodecContext == nullptr) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }

    // Setting parameters
    m_AudioCodecContext->bit_rate = _bitRate;
    m_AudioCodecContext->sample_rate = _sampleRate;
    m_AudioCodecContext->sample_fmt = _format;
    m_AudioCodecContext->channels = _channel;

    m_AudioCodecContext->channel_layout = av_get_default_channel_layout(_channel);
    m_AudioCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    // Turn on the encoder
    int result = avcodec_open2(m_AudioCodecContext, m_AudioCodec, nullptr);
    if (result < 0) {
        avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
        if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return;
    }

    // Create a package
    if (!initFormat(_fileName)) {
        avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
        if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return;
    }

    // write to the file header
    result = avformat_write_header(m_FormatContext, nullptr);
    if (result < 0) {
        avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
        if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return;
    }

    // Create Frame
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (frame == nullptr) {
        avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
        if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return;
    }

    int nb_samples = 0;
    if (m_AudioCodecContext->codec->capabilities & AV_CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE) {
        nb_samples = 10000;
    }
    else {
        nb_samples = m_AudioCodecContext->frame_size;
    }

    // Set the parameters of the Frame
    frame->nb_samples = nb_samples;
    frame->format = m_AudioCodecContext->sample_fmt;
    frame->channel_layout = m_AudioCodecContext->channel_layout;

    // Apply for data memory
    result = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (result < 0) {
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        {
            avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
            if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
                avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Set the Frame to be writable
    result = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
    if (result < 0) {
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        {
            avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
            if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
                avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
            return;
        }
    }

    int perFrameDataSize = frame->linesize[0];
    int count = _pcmData.size() / perFrameDataSize;
    bool needAddOne = false;
    if (_pcmData.size() % perFrameDataSize != 0) {
        count++;
        needAddOne = true;
    }

    int frameCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Create a Packet
        AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (pkt == nullptr) {
            avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
            if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
                avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
            return;
        }
        av_init_packet(pkt);

        if (i == count - 1)
            perFrameDataSize = _pcmData.size() % perFrameDataSize;

        // Synthesize WAV files
        memset(frame->data[0], 0, perFrameDataSize);
        memcpy(frame->data[0], &(_pcmData.data()[perFrameDataSize * i]), perFrameDataSize);

        frame->pts = frameCount++;
        // send Frame
        result = avcodec_send_frame(m_AudioCodecContext, frame);
        if (result < 0)
            continue;

        // Receive the encoded Packet
        result = avcodec_receive_packet(m_AudioCodecContext, pkt);
        if (result < 0) {
            av_packet_free(&pkt);
            continue;
        }

        // write to file
        av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, m_AudioCodecContext->time_base, m_FormatContext->streams[0]->time_base);
        pkt->stream_index = 0;
        result = av_interleaved_write_frame(m_FormatContext, pkt);
        if (result < 0)
            continue;

        av_packet_free(&pkt);
    }

    // write to the end of the file
    av_write_trailer(m_FormatContext);
    // Close file IO
    avio_closep(&m_FormatContext->pb);
    // Release Frame memory
    av_frame_free(&frame);

    avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
    if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
        avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_TRACE);

    QFile file("rawDataOfPcmAlawType.bin");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    QByteArray rawData(file.readAll());

    AudioGenerater generator;
    generator.generateAudioFileWithOptions(
               "test.mka",
               rawData,
               1, 
               64000, 
               8000,
               AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);

    return 0;
}
```

**ВАЖНО** Помочь найти самый подходящий вариант записи `pcm_alaw` или различного от этого формата данных в `mka` аудиофайл.

**UPD** Использование `FFMPEG` как отдельный процесс к сожаление запрешен.

Comment: а можно пример `rawData` на «поиграться»? после создания opus-энкодера его параметры как по ссылке в `m_AudioCodecContext` не забыл установить?

Comment: @Fat-Zer, Я не полностью понял ваш вопрос:
    `после создания opus-энкодера его параметры как по ссылке в m_AudioCodecContext не забыл установить?`. `m_AudioCodecContext` принимает созданный контекст энкодера благодаря `avcodec_alloc_context3` функции, принимающий сам энкодер.

Comment: я имею в виду, не забыл samplerate задать и прочее для выходного (и входного) кодека?... По вопросу — то что `ffmpeg` выбирается именно opus — простое совпадение — если кодек выходного формата не задан, то он просто выбирает тот, который был задан для данного формата контейнера по умолчанию во время сборки libav... у меня, например, это vorbis. см. `ffmpeg --help muser=matroska` для своего значения... программно можно получить с помощью `av_guess_codec()`... так что если opus не принципиален, то можешь использовать любой формат... хоть в том же pcm_alaw оставить и завернуть в матрёшку...

Comment: я бы собрал riff wav контейнер - он легко делается без ffmeg, а потом конвертнул его целиком

Comment: @eri, проблема в том, что на самом деле, при получение `RTP` пакетов с полезной нагрузкой `pcm_alaw`, я должен сохранять эти пакеты в временный буффер, и после определенного заполнения этого буфера даннымы, сохранять их в аудиофайл. Данный аудиофайл должен быть всегда открыт, так как я буду получать `RTP` пакеты из определенного стрима (который в теории, будет отправлять RTP пакеты для записи 24/7). для дальнейшей обработки и записи в аудиофайл формата `mka`.

Comment: для записи 24/7 я бы рекомендовал hls или что-то подобное. плэйлист с чанками по 10 мегабайт. один большой файл легко повредить...

Comment: @eri, `один большой файл легко повредить...` - согласен с Вами. Мы и не будем записывать 24/7 аудиоданные в один файл (это очень глупо и непрактично). Возможно, мы будем разделять записывающие аудиоданные по определенному характеру ( например, записывать стрим по 1 часу на файл).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Задача моего проекта заключается в том, чтобы просто взять pcm_alaw данные и запаковать их в контейнер, формата mka.

С такой формулировкой, самым простым вариантом будет скармливать весь поток ffmpeg'у и «демуксить» его встроенной заглушкой для сырого кодека; а потом просто муксить дорожку из потока в mkv «как есть», без перекодирования:

```
// build : g++ -g3 -O0 -std=c++17 -lavformat -lavutil -lavcodec  ./av_muxrecorder.cpp -o muxer
// run   : ./muxer rawData foo.mka

#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <memory>
#include <cassert>

extern "C" {
#include <libavcodec/avcodec.h>
#include <libavformat/avformat.h>
#include <libavutil/error.h>
#include <libavutil/log.h>
}

#undef av_err2str
#define av_err2str(errnum) \
  av_make_error_string((char*)alloca(AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE), AV_ERROR_MAX_STRING_SIZE, errnum)

using namespace std::string_literals;

template <>
struct std::default_delete<AVFormatContext> {
    void operator()(AVFormatContext* p) const noexcept { avformat_free_context(p); }
};

template <>
struct std::default_delete<AVCodecContext> {
    void operator()(AVCodecContext* p) const noexcept { avcodec_free_context(&p); }
};

template <>
struct std::default_delete<AVIOContext> {
    void operator()(AVIOContext* p) const noexcept { 
        if (p) { av_freep(&p->buffer); }
        avio_context_free(&p);
    }
};

class MuxRecorder {
    std::unique_ptr<AVFormatContext> inCtx;
    std::unique_ptr<AVIOContext> inIOCtx;
    std::unique_ptr<AVCodecContext> inCodecCtx;
    AVStream* inStream;

    std::shared_ptr<AVFormatContext> outCtx;
    AVStream* outStream;

    const uint8_t *curData;
    size_t curSz;
    bool isFinished;

public:
  MuxRecorder (AVInputFormat *fmt, AVDictionary **inOpts);
  void setOutput (std::shared_ptr<AVFormatContext> outCtx_);

  void processData(const uint8_t *data, size_t sz);
  void finalize();

protected:
  void doProcessStream();

private:
  /// служебная функция, используется как callback в AVIOContext
  static int readPacket(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int sz);
};

MuxRecorder::MuxRecorder (AVInputFormat *fmt, AVDictionary **inOpts)
  :curData(0),
   curSz(0),
   isFinished(0)
{
  int rc;

  const size_t ioBufSz = 4096; // должен быть не меньше, чем размер пакета кодека,
    // может быть самостоятельно увеличен libav
  uint8_t *ioCtxBuffer = (uint8_t*)av_malloc(ioBufSz);
  if(!ioCtxBuffer) throw std::bad_alloc();

  inIOCtx.reset(avio_alloc_context(
        /* buffer */ ioCtxBuffer, /* buffer_size */ ioBufSz, /* write_flag */0, 
        /* user_data */ this,
        /* read  */ &MuxRecorder::readPacket,
        /* write */ 0,
        /* seek  */ 0));

  if (!inIOCtx) {
    av_free(ioCtxBuffer);
    throw std::bad_alloc();
  } // В сллучае успеха inIOCtx принимает владение буфером ioCtxBuffer


  /********* Создание контекста для демультиплексера формата ***********/
  
  // для pcml это будет просто заглушка
  AVFormatContext *fmtCtx = avformat_alloc_context();
  if(!fmtCtx) throw std::bad_alloc();
  fmtCtx->pb = inIOCtx.get();
  // TODO: для более сложных форматов это должно делаться в processData()
  rc = avformat_open_input(&fmtCtx, 0, fmt, inOpts);
  if (rc < 0) {
    // avformat_open_input() освобождает fmtCtx при неудаче
    throw std::runtime_error( "Failed to open input: "s.append(av_err2str(rc)) );
  }
  inCtx.reset(fmtCtx);

  if (inCtx->nb_streams != 1) { // для простого формата поток должен быть один
    throw std::runtime_error("Input has several streams");
  }

  inStream = inCtx->streams[0];

  /********* Определение кодека входного потока ************************/
  // для сырых кодеков, в частности, pcml это формальность,
  // id должен совпдать с fmt->raw_codec_id
  AVCodec *inCodec = avcodec_find_decoder(inStream->codecpar->codec_id);
  if (!inCodec) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Couldn't find codec for input stream");
  }

  inCodecCtx.reset(avcodec_alloc_context3(inCodec));
  if(!inCodecCtx) throw std::bad_alloc();

  avcodec_parameters_to_context (inCodecCtx.get(), inStream->codecpar);
  rc = avcodec_open2(inCodecCtx.get(), inCodec, inOpts);
  if (rc < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error( "Failed to open codec context: "s.append(av_err2str(rc)) );
  }
}

void MuxRecorder::setOutput (std::shared_ptr<AVFormatContext> outCtx_) {
  outCtx.swap(outCtx_);

  // добавить поток данных в файл
  outStream = avformat_new_stream(outCtx.get(), NULL);
  if(!outStream) { throw std::bad_alloc(); }
  int rc = avcodec_parameters_copy(outStream->codecpar, inStream->codecpar);
  if (rc < 0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("Failed to copy parameters: "s.append(av_err2str(rc)));
  }
  outStream->codecpar->codec_tag = 0;
}

void MuxRecorder::finalize() {
  isFinished = 1;
  doProcessStream(); // обработать остаток входных данных

  // Закрытие контекста входных данных. 
  AVFormatContext *fmtCtx = inCtx.release();
  avformat_close_input(&fmtCtx);
}

void MuxRecorder::processData(const uint8_t *data, size_t sz) {
  // В некотором роде хак т.к. при любой ошибке в readPacket() 
  // (в том числе и EAGAIN) ffmpeg устанавливает этот флаг в своих нутрах
  if(inIOCtx->error == AVERROR(EAGAIN)) {
      inIOCtx->eof_reached = 0;
  }

  curData = data;
  curSz   = sz;

  doProcessStream(); // собственно обработать данные из буыера

  assert(curSz == 0); // к этому моменту ffmpeg должен вычитаться всё
}


void MuxRecorder::doProcessStream() {
  AVPacket pkt;

  while(1) {
    int rc = av_read_frame(inCtx.get(), &pkt);
    if(rc == AVERROR(EAGAIN) || rc == AVERROR_EOF ) {
      break;
    } else if (rc<0) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read packet: "s.append(av_err2str(rc)));
    } else if(pkt.stream_index == inStream->index) { //< проверка для галочки
        /* copy packet */
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q_rnd( pkt.pts, inStream->time_base, outStream->time_base,
                               (enum AVRounding) (AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX) );
        pkt.dts = av_rescale_q_rnd( pkt.dts, inStream->time_base, outStream->time_base,
                               (enum AVRounding) (AV_ROUND_NEAR_INF | AV_ROUND_PASS_MINMAX) );
        pkt.duration = av_rescale_q(pkt.duration, inStream->time_base, outStream->time_base);
        pkt.pos = -1;
        rc = av_interleaved_write_frame(outCtx.get(), &pkt);
        if (rc < 0) {
          av_packet_unref(&pkt);
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to mux packet into output stream: "s
                     .append(av_err2str(rc)));
        }
        av_packet_unref(&pkt);
    }
  }
}

int MuxRecorder::readPacket(void *opaque, uint8_t *buf, int sz) {
  MuxRecorder* self = (MuxRecorder*) opaque;

  if(self->curData && self->curSz) {
    sz = std::min(sz,(int) self->curSz);
    memcpy(buf, self->curData, sz);
    self->curSz -= sz;
    self->curData += sz;
    return sz;
  } else if(self->isFinished) {
    return AVERROR_EOF;
  } else {
    return AVERROR(EAGAIN);
  }
}

/*######## Helper functions #########################################*/

std::unique_ptr<AVFormatContext> openOutfile (const char *ofname) {
  // открыть поток для файла
  AVFormatContext *fmtCtx=0;
  int rc = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&fmtCtx, NULL, NULL, ofname);
  if(rc<0) {
    throw std::runtime_error("failed to crate context for output file: "s.append(av_err2str(rc)));
  }

  if (!(fmtCtx->oformat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
    rc = avio_open(&fmtCtx->pb, ofname, AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
    if (rc < 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error("failed to open output file ("s.append(ofname)
              .append("): ").append(av_err2str(rc)));
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not open output file '%s'", ofname);
    }
  }

  return std::unique_ptr<AVFormatContext>(fmtCtx);
};

/*######## main() example ###########################################*/

int main ( int argc, char *argv[] ) {

  if(argc!=3) {
    std::cerr << "Usage: " << argv [0] << " <infile> <outfile>" << std::endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
  }
  const char *ifname = argv[1];
  const char *ofname = argv[2];

  int rc, rv = EXIT_SUCCESS;

  av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_TRACE);

  AVInputFormat *fmt = av_find_input_format("alaw");
  assert (fmt);

  AVDictionary *inOpts = 0;
  // Sets the sample rate of the output file.
  av_dict_set(&inOpts, "sample_rate", "8000", 0);
  // Sets the number of channels for the output file.
  av_dict_set(&inOpts, "channels", "1", 0);

  try {
    constexpr size_t bufSz = 1024;
    uint8_t buf[bufSz];

    
    MuxRecorder sr(fmt, &inOpts);
    std::shared_ptr<AVFormatContext> outCtx{openOutfile(ofname)};

    sr.setOutput(outCtx);
    av_dict_free (&inOpts);

    rc = avformat_write_header(outCtx.get(), 0);

    if(rc< 0) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to write output header: "s.append(av_err2str(rc)) );
    }

    std::ifstream is(ifname, std::ios::binary | std::ios::in);
    if(!is) {
      throw std::runtime_error("Failed to open input file: "s.append(strerror(errno)));
    }

    do {
      is.read((char*)buf, bufSz);
      sr.processData(buf, is.gcount());
    } while (is);

    sr.finalize();
    
    rc = av_write_trailer(outCtx.get());
    if(rc<0) {
      throw std::runtime_error( "Failed to finalize output file: "s.append(av_err2str(rc)) );
    }
  } catch(std::exception &e) {
    av_dict_free (&inOpts);
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    rv = EXIT_FAILURE;
  }

  return rv;
}
// PS:
//
// I'm the author of this code snippet and hereby grant it to public domain.
// Я, автор данного отрывка кода, передаю его в общественное достояние.
```

#### Некоторые замечания:

- Данные на вход можно подавать произвольными фрагментами, у ffmpeg есть внутренняя буферезация, так что всё должно работать независимо от размера блока.
- Не особо отлаживал, так что возможны ошибки.
- Отдельно стоит проверить на утечки памяти.
- Не должно составить сложности упаковывать несколько дорожек в один контейнер (в том числе видео).
- В качестве поддерживаемого потока на вход `MuxRecorder`'у должно быть возможно подать любой, поддерживаемый ffmpeg (с видео также не должно возникнуть проблем).
- Если перекодирование всё же необходимо, то на данный пример можно накрутить вариант с ресампленгом, как в примере `transcode_aac.c`/ответе **@bbdd**.

---

#### Полезные ссылки:

- Относительно хороший обзор последовательности обработки данных в libav: [ffmpeg-libav-tutorial](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial)
- Пример чтения из памяти в ffmpeg: [`avio_reading.c`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_reading_8c-example.html)
- Пример муксинга потоков: [`remuxing.c`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/remuxing_8c-example.html)

---

> Благодаря комментарию пользователя Fat-Zer, было определено, что лучше всего использовать для определения кодека - av_guess_codec() функцию, которая в свою очередь, автоматически подбирает нужный идентификатор кодека.

Определённости ради, я не говорил, что так делать «лучше всего». Я просто обозначил, что так поступает ffmpeg, если пользователь не указал кодек. И можно использовать любой кодек на свой выбор. ИМХО, в своём полноценном приложении, этот выбор надо или дать пользователю, или сделать заранее самому, а не полагаться на то, как был собран ffmpeg.

Comment: у меня появился вопрос. При попытке записать `OPUS`, `ffmpeg` выдает вот такую ошибку: `Unknown input format: 'opus'`. После просмотра всех поддерживаемых форматов библиотеки, было определено, что формат `opus` поддерживается лишь для кодирования. Из за этого, я указал ему `ogg` формат, но в таком случаи, `ffmpeg` не можеот открыть файл, выдавая такую вот ошибку: `"Could not open input file: /home/test/output.mka (error: Resource temporarily unavailable)"`. Есть ли возможность решить эту проблему.

Comment: @bbdd, надо смотреть что ты именно ему подсовываешь... если сырую последовательность, которую получаешь от RTP, то по идее с opus'ом способ описанный в ответе не прокатит — в нём в нагрузке не должно быть информации о разбивке на пакеты, так что по идее придётся вручную из каждого RTP-пакета формировать `AVPaket` и отправлять в декодер или в муксер...

Comment: я отправляю только необработанную последовательность, полученную из полезной нагрузки пакета `RTP`. Как Вы думаете, [этот](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/muxing_8c-example.html) примет поможет решить эту проблему, так как я еще не разбирал особенности формирования `AVPacket`. Я так полагаю, что мне нужно смотреть в сторону `get_audio_frame` из приложенного примера (я про заполнение `AVPacket`). Но только вместо генерации синтетического звука, заполнять `AVFrame::data` полезной нагрузки `RTP` пакета ?

Comment: @bbdd, я бы сказал, что нет... я бы скорее ориентировался на [decode_audio](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/decode_audio_8c-example.html), только если декодирование не нужно, то вместо него я бы посылал пакет сразу в муксер... а ещё, возможно, нужно будет заполнить некоторые поля `AVPacket` вручную... ничего более определённого сказать, к сожалению, не могу...

Comment: большое Вам спасибо, Вы уже очень многим помогли. В моем случае, я думаю, что потребуется лишь муксер, так как, то что я получаю, записывается без изменений.

Comment: @Fat-Zer, здравствуйте, вы не могли посмотреть мой вопрос. Возможно вам будет интересно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1237154/%d0%9a%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%81%d1%8d%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%83%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-wasapi-%d0%b2-avframe-ffmpeg-c

Answer (score 2):

А что если запустить ffmpeg как процесс и кормить его буфером alaw через stdin?

```
dd if=/dev/urandom | ffmpeg -f alaw -i pipe: -c:a copy -f matroska  data.mka
```

Красивый шум пакуется без проблем.

А ещё ffmpeg сам умеет подключаться к rtp. Можно просто держать его в сабпроцессе.

Comment: спасибо большое за Ваш комментарий, но к сожалению, мне запрещено использовать какие либо процессы, тем более запуск `ffmpeg` как процесс. Могу работать лишь с самой библиотекой `ffmpeg`.

Comment: а можно на библиотеке зоздать пайп и запустить упаковщик в треде?

Comment: библиотека дает эту возможность, но работать с этим я тоже не могу.  В идеале, нужно просто получить `RTP` пакет, извлечь аудиоданные, и отправить пакет в временной буфер, а в свою очередь, другой поток просто бы обрабатывал этот пакек.

Comment: Отправка пакетов во временной буфер обязательна, так как `RTP` пакеты, приходят из вне, и есть процент того, что пакеты просто будут приходить не в правильном порядке, а может и вообще будут пропадать.

Comment: попробую на си написать.

Comment: я буду Вам очень признателен. Я пока дошел до того результата, что могу записать `pcm_alaw` в `wav` аудиофайл. Но при попытке записать в `mka` контейнер, у меня появляются ошибки, которые были упомянуты в самом вопросе.

Comment: просматривая [этот](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/transcode_aac_8c-example.html) пример, я наткнулся на такой вопрос: А что, если изминить методы для приема входного аудиофайла, которые в свою очередь, по расширению аудиофайла определяют какие настройки установить, на методы, которые принимают сырые данные, а также параметры самих данных, такие как **bit_rate**, **sample_rate**, **channels** и так далее, для будущих настроек. Что скажете насчет этого ?