# Конвертация сэмплов полученных с помощью wasapi в AVFrame FFmpeg & C++

Tags: c++, аудио, ffmpeg, encoder, capture

Необходима помощь в доработке метода по конвертации семплов и дальнейшей их записи в ac3 файл.

Сэмплы подаются на вход в виде BYTE* формате AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTенкодеру они необходимы в формате: AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP.

Вот прототип метода, который не работает:

```
bool AddAudioSample(AVFormatContext * pFormatContext, AVStream * pStream, BYTE * audiodata, uint32_t sampleCount, uint64_t devicets)
{
    AVCodecContext * pCodecCxt = NULL;
    bool res = true;

    pCodecCxt = pStream->codec;

    AVFrame*  pFLTAudioFrame = NULL;
    pFLTAudioFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    AVFrame*  pFLTPAudioFrame = NULL;
    pFLTPAudioFrame = av_frame_alloc();

    ProcessData(pFLTAudioFrame, pFLTPAudioFrame, (uint8_t *)audiodata, sampleCount, devicets);

    swr_convert(pSmplConvertCtx, pFLTPAudioFrame->data, pFLTPAudioFrame->nb_samples, (const uint8_t **)pFLTAudioFrame->data, pFLTAudioFrame->nb_samples);

    AVPacket pkt;
    av_init_packet(&pkt);

    pkt.flags |= AV_PKT_FLAG_KEY;
    pkt.stream_index = pStream->index;
    pkt.data = pAudioEncodeBuffer;
    pkt.size = pFLTPAudioFrame->pkt_size;

    int gotOutput = 0;
    auto ret = avcodec_encode_audio2(pCodecCxt, &pkt, pFLTPAudioFrame, &gotOutput);
    if (ret < 0)
    {
        exit(1);
    }
    if (gotOutput)
    {
        pkt.pts = av_rescale_q(pCodecCxt->coded_frame->pts, pCodecCxt->time_base, pStream->time_base);
        ret = av_interleaved_write_frame(pFormatContext, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0)
        {
            exit(1);
        }
    }

    return res;
}

void ProcessData(AVFrame *inputframe, AVFrame *outputFrame, uint8_t* data, uint32_t sample_count, uint64_t device_ts)
{
    inputframe->nb_samples = sample_count;
    inputframe->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT;
    inputframe->sample_rate = mWFX->nSamplesPerSec;
    inputframe->channels = mWFX->nChannels;
    inputframe->pkt_size = sample_count*mWFX->nBlockAlign;

    av_samples_fill_arrays(inputframe->data, inputframe->linesize, data, mWFX->nChannels, sample_count, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT, 1);

    outputFrame->nb_samples = inputframe->nb_samples;
    outputFrame->format = AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP;
    outputFrame->sample_rate = inputframe->sample_rate;
    outputFrame->channels = inputframe->channels;
    outputFrame->pkt_size = sample_count*mWFX->nBlockAlign;

    av_samples_fill_arrays(outputFrame->data, outputFrame->linesize, pAudioEncodeBuffer, mWFX->nChannels, sample_count, AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP, 1);
}
```

А здесь настройка контекста ресамплера и вычисление буфера пакета:

```
    pSmplConvertCtx = swr_alloc();
    if (!pSmplConvertCtx)
    {
         fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate resampler context\n");
         exit(1);
    }

    av_opt_set_int       (pSmplConvertCtx, "in_channel_count",   pCodecCxt->channels,       0);
    av_opt_set_int       (pSmplConvertCtx, "in_sample_rate",     pCodecCxt->sample_rate,    0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(pSmplConvertCtx, "in_sample_fmt",      AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT,         0);
    av_opt_set_int       (pSmplConvertCtx, "out_channel_count",  pCodecCxt->channels,       0);
    av_opt_set_int       (pSmplConvertCtx, "out_sample_rate",    pCodecCxt->sample_rate,    0);
    av_opt_set_sample_fmt(pSmplConvertCtx, "out_sample_fmt",     pCodecCxt->sample_fmt,     0);

    if ((swr_init(pSmplConvertCtx)) < 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize the resampling context\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    nSizeAudioEncodeBuffer = av_samples_get_buffer_size(NULL, pCodecCxt->channels, pCodecCxt->sample_rate, pCodecCxt->sample_fmt, 1);
    if (pAudioEncodeBuffer == NULL)
    {
        pAudioEncodeBuffer = (uint8_t * )av_malloc(nSizeAudioEncodeBuffer);
    }
```

Comment: Не вкурсе что там с ffmpeg, но этого Sleep(hnsActualDuration / REFTIMES_PER_MILLISEC / 2); в wasapi записи быть не должно.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков, интересно. Почему нормально пишется в wav файл через mmioWrite?

Comment: Откудаж мне знать, может пока никакой работы нет и так работает. Там вроде был способ точно узнать когда подсунуть буфер ему, а не юзать sleep.

Comment: @SergeyZinovev, особо умного ничего сказать не смогу... можешь пример [encode_audio.c](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/4.0/encode_audio_8c-example.html) из стандартного набора посмотреть... из непонятного — нужно только выяснить, в каком формате win выдаёт эти аудиоданные...

Comment: @Fat-Zer, я дополнил свой пост ответом на Ваш вопрос.

Comment: @SergeyZinovev, нум, тогда, опять же, смотри пример выше... если кодек поддерживает этот формат семплов, тогда проблем быть не должно... если нет, то придётся делать ресамлинг...

Comment: Ваши данные - исходя из приведенного - почти но не в точности `AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP`: они interlaved, а вам нужны planar. Соответственно нужно воспользоваться преобразованием или же просто вручную попереставлять байты чтобы получить отдельные per canal planes.

Comment: @RomanR., здравствуйте, я попытался сделать прототип метода, который конвертирует фрейм одного формата в другой. Однако у меня ничего не вышло. Я прошу помощи в доработке этого метода.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Аудиоданные в Windows API повсюду в виде сплошного массива, т.е. interleaved в терминах libav. В то же время в самом libav многие кодеки сделаны так, что им нужны planar данные, то есть разобранные по каналам. Сами "значения" отдельных семплов при этом - те же самые. То есть в конце концов, разница лишь в том, выделены ли отдельно каналы (`AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLTP`) или нет (`AV_SAMPLE_FMT_FLT`).

По большому счету нет нужды перераспределять байты вызовом внешнего API, т.к. всё, что нужно сделать, по сути укладывается в такой цикл:

```
UINT ChannelCount = ...; // каналов аудио
FLOAT const* Input = reinterpret_cast<FLOAT const*>(...); // из WASAPI
AVFrame* Frame = ...; // подготовка фрейма для кодека
// ниже предполагается что nb_samples уже указывает количество сэмплов в буфере, а data указывает на массивы, 
// для кадого канала которые можно инициализировать отдельно или взять один общий блок памяти и в нем выделить
// отдельные куски для каждого канала
for(INT S = 0; S < Frame->nb_samples; S++)
    for(UINT C = 0; C < ChannelCount; C++)
    {
        FLOAT const& I = Input[S * ChannelCount + C];
        FLOAT& O = reinterpret_cast<FLOAT*>(Frame->data[C])[S];
        O = I;
    }
```

То же самое, конечно, можно сделать и средствами libav.

См. также [What is the difference between AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16P and AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18889127/868014)

Comment: Говоря ретроспективно, я думаю, что это не тот ответ на который вы рассчитывали. Но тем не менее, это лучший ответ для того вопроса, который вы сформулировали. Что бы в целом могло помочь: вы бы могли собрать простенький проект, который можно быстро скомпилировать постороннему человек, и залить на гитхаб, оставив здесь ссылку. Поправить ваш код на компилируемом проекте несложно, а по кускам кода - сложно. В том виде, в котором вы спросили вам, по сути, остаётся ждать чтобы кто-то с сильно специфичным опытом вам помог. Но такой человек не всегда находится.